# How can I write "exit" word to txt from bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo, windows-scripting

I want to write to **txt** from **bat file**

### I write this code:

```
@echo off
cd C:\test_folder
set st1=cd  newfolder/
set st2=mget xxxx*.csv
set st3=exit 0
echo %st1%> test2.bat
echo %st2%>>test2.bat
echo %st3%>>test2.bat
```

### Bu the output is (test2.bat) :

```
cd  newfolder/
mget xxxx*.csv
```

and the **"exit"** word is missed.

How can I do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: because your resulting line is `echo exit 0>>test2.bat` - where `0>>test2.bat` redirects the output of `echo exit` to the file. In your file, you should just read `echo`.  Worse with `exit 1`: `1` means ErrorStream, which is empty here, so your file would receive nothing at all. Whenever your line may end in a number, better use a different syntax: `>>test2.bat echo exit 0`

Comment: thanks it works please answer and I accept answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because your resulting line is `echo exit 0>>test2.bat` - where `0>>test2.bat` tries to redirect the INPUT (STDIN) of `echo exit` to the file. This results in an empty output to the file and the word `echo` on the screen.
`echo exit 1>>test2.bat` would redirect STDOUT ("normal" output) of `echo exit` to the file (which is just the word `exit`).
Even worse with `exit 2`: `2` means ErrorStream, which is empty here, so your file would receive nothing at all, but STDOUT still goes to screen.

Whenever your line may end in a number, better use a different syntax:

```
>>test2.bat echo exit 0
```

or

```
(echo exit 0)>>test2.bat
```

If you have to write several lines, you can even write all of them in one go (instead of opening the file for each file separately, write the line, close the file before opening it again for writing the next line)

```
>test2.bat (
  echo %st1%
  echo %st2%
  echo %st3%
)
```